# Вставка SWF  в HTML

Tags: flash, html, swf

Ребят, всем привет, помогите разобраться.

```
<object
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/images/template/1.swf"
width="367" height="160">
<param name="movie" value="/images/template/1.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

Вот так картинка работает при наведении, двигается, но, как ни пробую, не прилепляется ссылка, swf - как кнопочка должен работать.

А вот так...

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <a style="position: absolute; width: 367px; height: 160px; left: 0; top: 0; background: url(/images/template/1.swf) left top no-repeat;" href="http://distira.ru" target="_blank"></a>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/images/template/1.swf" width="367" height="160">
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
        <param name="movie" value="/images/template/1.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Работает ссылка, но не двигается картинка, просто статичной становится.

Comment: @sajkova, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML-линьки "a href=" используемые на sfw, некоторые браузеры и CMS не понимают.
Делайте в самой flash action OnClick на нужный вам url.

Comment: скорее дело в cms тогда.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте убрать background: `url(/images/template/1.swf)` и добавить `display:block`.

Comment: не помогает и так.

Comment: залейте флешку на rghost.ru и дайте ссылку на файл.

Answer (score -1):

У Вас есть в swf- файле такой синтаксис:

```
имя.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotopage);
function gotopage(event:MouseEvent): void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.сайт.ru"), "_blank");
}
```